# Validation does not fire...right away, and not fully

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have html like this:

```
                <form action="" id="emailFillOutForm">
                <div class="txt-fld">
                    <label for="repName">Rep. Name</label>
                    <input id="repName" type="text" disabled="disabled" value="John Smith" class="disabled" /> <!-- This value will come from login, fake it for now -->
                    <label for="financedAmount" style="padding-left: 15px;">Financed Amount</label>
                    <input id="financedAmount" type="text" disabled="disabled" class="disabled" />
                </div>
                <div class="txt-fld">
                    <label for="doctorName">Doctor Name</label>
                    <input id="doctorName" type="text" class="required"/>
                    <label for="emailAddress" style="padding-left: 15px;">Email address</label>
                    <input id="emailAddress" type="text" class="required email"/>
                </div>
                <div class="txt-fld">
                    <label>Equipment</label>
                    <select name="equipment" class="required">
                        <option value="Equipment1" selected="selected">Equipment1</option>
                        <option value="Equipment2">Equipment2</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-fld">
                    <button type="submit" value="submit">Submit &raquo;</button>
                </div>
             </form>
```

Javascript as follows:

```
    // Validate submit form with the jQuery validation library
        $("#emailFillOutForm").validate({
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                error.appendTo($(element.parent("div")));
            },
            rules: {
                emailAddress: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                }
            }
        });
```

jquery.validate.min.js library v. 1.9
jquery-1.7.2.min

For some reason, "submitting" the form only validates the name input, to get the email validated I have to tab over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that all you need to add is `name` attribute with identical value as `id` to your inputs.

[...]

```
<input id="doctorName" name"doctorName" type="text" class="required"/>
```

[...]

```
<input id="emailAddress" name="emailAddress" type="text" class="required email"/>
```

[...]

Comment: When i run in the latest v. of chrome, it doesn't work for me.

Comment: When you pressed submit, only one error message is shown.  I want all error messages displayed when a form is submitted and multiple things are wrong